# Combination of Animal Pairs

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A given data set consists of 15 animals in 5 distinct groups, and has the following composition:  1 "cat", 2 "dog", 3 "cow", 4 "ape", and 5 "pig" (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15). Applying COMBIN(15,2) formula would then yield a total combination of 105 pairs of animals.  I can programmatically generate all possible combinations, but I have a hard time of visualizing the combinations express in term of COMBIN formula(s). So here is my question using {pig, cow} as an example: What is the probability of {pig, cow} combinations in term of COMBIN formula(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting exactly one pig and exactly one cow in a random drawing from the collection you
specify, consider that the collection has 3 cows, 5 pigs, and 7 other kinds
of animals. Then the desired probability is
$$\frac{{3 \choose 1}{5 \choose 1}{7 \choose 0}}{{15 \choose 2}}.$$